# How to check if an IP address is the local host on a multi-homed system?

Tags: java

For a machine with multiple NIC cards, is there a convenient method in Java that tells whether a given IP address is the current machine or not.  e.g.

```
boolean IsThisMyIpAddress("192.168.220.25");
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

If you are looking for any IP address that is valid for the local host then you must check for special local host (e.g. 127.0.0.1) addresses as well as the ones assigned to any interfaces. For instance...

```java
public static boolean isThisMyIpAddress(InetAddress addr) {
    // Check if the address is a valid special local or loop back
    if (addr.isAnyLocalAddress() || addr.isLoopbackAddress())
        return true; // Was local sub-net.

    // Check if the Non-local address is defined on any Local-interface.
    try {
        return NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(addr) != null;
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

With a string, indicating the port, call this with:

```java
boolean isMyDesiredIp = false;
try
{
    isMyDesiredIp = isThisMyIpAddress(InetAddress.getByName("192.168.220.25")); //"localhost" for localhost
}
catch(UnknownHostException unknownHost)
{
    unknownHost.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: That should be InetAddress.getHostName("ip comes here") ... getbyHostName does not exist.

Comment: @AbhijeetKashnia: Thanks, but actually it should be `InetAddress.getByName()`, `getHostName()` is an object method, not a class method and it does something different (it gets the host name for the IP address, such as using a reverse DNS lookup).