# How to check if URL is the local machine?

Tags: java, spring, url

I have a [java.net.URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) object in a Spring 4 [@RestController](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html). How can I check if the URL (HTTP) leads to the current machine (this Spring application) or is an URL to an external HTTP-Source?

---

- I found [out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2349535/1123743) that java.net.URL does hostname resolution to compare to other URL object. Is there a way to reuse this resolution to not having to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I love those stack overflow guys who downvote questions without leaving a hint about what's wrong. :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the code from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406341/how-to-check-if-an-ip-address-is-the-local-host-on-a-multi-homed-system#answer-2406819) you can check if it is a local IP. You should pass an `InetAddress` object, so get it from your URL using the following command:

```
InetAddress.getByName(new URL(urlString).getHost());
```

Comment: InetAddress.getByName(), when called on a non-numeric IP, results in a reverse DNS lookup (meaning that it goes out to network). This may be problematic in certain cases.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use `InetAddress` class to check this.

1.First get the local system IP address

```
      String localAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
```

2.Fetch the address of url that you want to match.

```
      String requestAddress = InetAddress.getByName(new URL(url).getHost()).getHostAddress();
```

Now you can compare both 1 and 2 address string.

I hope it helps!!!

Comment: Why is your code not beeing shown as code? Tried to edit it to make that answer more awesome and failed! :)

Comment: This wont work. localAddress returns my ip address (eg. 172.12.34.56) and requestAddress returns 127.0.0.1 Comparison will return false but they will resolve to the same address.