# Spark 2: check if node is driver or worker

Tags: apache-spark

I have a Spark 2 application that uses grpc so that client applications can connect to it.

However, I want the grpc code only to be started on the driver node and not on the workers.

Is there a possibility in Spark 2 to check if the node the code is currently running on is the driver node?

Comment: Are you talking about *where the driver is ran* from?

Comment: Yes! I would like to check if the code running is run as part of the driver or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the driver hostname by:

```
sc.getConf.get("spark.driver.host")
```

Comment: so checking for: `java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName() == mainContext.sc.getConf.get("spark.driver.host")` should allow me to do the check I guess

Comment: rather than checking equality, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406341/how-to-check-if-an-ip-address-is-the-local-host-on-a-multi-homed-system

Comment: I don't think this is safe at all, if you run your code in local mode or yarn-cluster, your executor can land in the same position than your drivers.

Answer (score 5):

I don't like the way to do it using "hosts", you depend on matching the right interface and also, same node can contain both drivers and masters. Personally, I set a environment variable

```
spark.executorEnv.RUNNING_ON_EXECUTOR=yes
```

and then in my code (using Python here, but it should work in any other language):

```
import os
if "RUNNING_ON_EXECUTOR" in os.environ:
       //Run executor code
else:
       //run driver code
```

Answer (score 0):

We can tell a node is the driver when TaskContext.get() is None normally, unless TaskContext is created explicitly in the driver for testing purposes.